# Designing and Printing Labels with Angular or Vanilla JS for CAB Printer, A6 Paper Size

Tags: javascript, angular, printing

I am working on a project where I need to design and print labels using either Angular or Vanilla JS. The target printer is a CAB printer, and the paper size is assumed to be A6, although there might be some uncertainty about it. The paper already contains a barcode, and my task is to print additional text on the label.

If you have experience with CAB printers in a similar context or if you can share insights on label printing with Angular or Vanilla JS, your input would be valuable.

Experimented with @media print for styling and fired off window.print(). However, faced issues with label layout and the existing barcode. It seems the standard print setup might not be the right fit for the CAB printer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.